# Upgrading from Python 2.6 to Python 2.7 in Django product

Tags: python, django, windows, upgrade

Django version 1.5.2
Operating System : Windows

I am trying to upgrade python that i use for Django project from 2.6 to 2.7. I have made respective changes in the following files

1. The path is setup properly to point to new python 2.7
2. Third party packages are properly updated/reinstalled with python 2.7
3. Made changes in *.wsgi file so as to include new installed thirdparty packages
4. http.conf has been changed to Directory tag of WSGIScriptAlias

However when i tried connecting the server through browser, i am getting the following exception

```
Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=6184): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'E:/Build/ACS/umonitor/ngnms/apache_django.wsgi'.
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "E:/Build/ACS/umonitor/ngnms/apache_django.wsgi", line 1, in <module>
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     import os, sys
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "E:\\Build\\ACS\\umonitor\\bin\\.\\\\..\\python\\Lib\\os.py", line 398, in <module>
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     import UserDict
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "E:\\Build\\ACS\\umonitor\\bin\\.\\\\..\\python\\Lib\\UserDict.py", line 84, in <module>
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     _abcoll.MutableMapping.register(IterableUserDict)
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "E:\\Build\\ACS\\umonitor\\bin\\.\\\\..\\python\\Lib\\abc.py", line 109, in register
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     if issubclass(subclass, cls):
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "E:\\Build\\ACS\\umonitor\\bin\\.\\\\..\\python\\Lib\\abc.py", line 184, in __subclasscheck__
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     cls._abc_negative_cache.add(subclass)
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "E:\\Build\\ACS\\umonitor\\bin\\.\\\\..\\python\\Lib\\_weakrefset.py", line 84, in add
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self.data.add(ref(item, self._remove))
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'classobj' object
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=6184): Target WSGI script 'E:/Build/ACS/umonitor/ngnms/apache_django.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=6184): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'E:/Build/ACS/umonitor/ngnms/apache_django.wsgi'.
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "E:/Build/ACS/umonitor/ngnms/apache_django.wsgi", line 1, in <module>
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     import os, sys
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "E:\\Build\\ACS\\umonitor\\bin\\.\\\\..\\python\\Lib\\os.py", line 398, in <module>
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     import UserDict
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "E:\\Build\\ACS\\umonitor\\bin\\.\\\\..\\python\\Lib\\UserDict.py", line 84, in <module>
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     _abcoll.MutableMapping.register(IterableUserDict)
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "E:\\Build\\ACS\\umonitor\\bin\\.\\\\..\\python\\Lib\\abc.py", line 109, in register
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     if issubclass(subclass, cls):
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "E:\\Build\\ACS\\umonitor\\bin\\.\\\\..\\python\\Lib\\abc.py", line 184, in __subclasscheck__
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     cls._abc_negative_cache.add(subclass)
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "E:\\Build\\ACS\\umonitor\\bin\\.\\\\..\\python\\Lib\\_weakrefset.py", line 84, in add
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self.data.add(ref(item, self._remove))
[Sun May 18 20:55:41 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'classobj' object
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a new version of mod_wsgi that has been compiled for Python 2.7.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I did the same. I downloaded mod_wsgi.so compiled for python 2.7 for windows from this URL http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi. I have already installed 64 bit python 2.7. Further i made changes related to mod_wsgi in httpd.conf file too. When i start apache it throws error Cannot load E:/Build/ACS/umonitor/apache22/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. Is there any changes related to python required

Comment: Just now got to see my apache is 32 bit. I would cross check and update